# How does git merge two branches automatically?

Tags: git

My question is based on the example at: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

[image]

Taken the example:

1. Set variable = 2 in Commit C2, then change to variable = 4 in C4 and back to variable = 2 in C5
2. Make a `git merge master <branch of iss53>`, resulting in `Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.`
3. The variable is 4.

**But why?**

I expected: As the ancestor sets variable = 2 and the commit (iss53) also sets variable = 2 the result after merge should be 2. Because the common ancestor and the newest version has set variable = 2

Is this behaviour depending on the merge strategy?

**edit**: I forgot to mention, that I changed variable = 3 in C3. But the result is the same.

Comment: If I understand your scenario correctly, the line is unchanged in commit C2, C3 and C5 but has changed in C4. That is, the line is part of the diff C2..C4. C2..C5 has no changes in that line so that the C2..C4 change is introduced in the merge result. Try setting `variable = 3" in C5 and you should get a merge conflict. Note that the commit (and also the author) times are irrelevant for merging. (As an aside, your sentence "and back to variable = 2 in C5" is misleading because as I understand it the line stayed the same in C3 -> C5; there was no "back".)

Comment: +1 for Tom's answer. Git does a very good job with merges, but it cannot read the user's intent for the code. This scenario demonstrates why it is generally considered ill-advised to merge into the master branch blind. Whenever possible, merge the master branch into the feature branch to bring it "up to date." Then you can verify the merge and test *before* bringing the updated code into the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of which revision is chronologically newer. It's a matter of the content of the branches that you are merging and the content of the *common* ancestor.

C2 says 2, C5 says 2 (so no change from C2), C4 says 4 (there's a change) so git will keep it to be 4 after merging.

You might have funky scenarios like setting the value to be 6 on C3, then 2 on C5..... in this case there's *again* no change from C2 so the end result would be 4 because there's no change between C2 and C5 (even though there was a change in the middle).

Comment: I think I understand now: C3 is irrelevant, because it has been updated by C5. iss53 finally says variable = 2, so there is no change comparing iss53 and the common ancestor. But then C4 appears and changes the common ancestor. No git has a change from 2 to 4 and leaves it at 4. Is that right?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if the steps you listed are verbatim what actually happened, but if so, then in commit `C3` the variable still has the value 2, and in fact the variable's value is unchanged since commit `C2` in the `iss53` branch.  You then merged `master` into `iss53`.  This brought in what Git perceived to be a change coming from a feature branch, that change being that the variable now has the value 4.  Git kept the version coming from `master`, and this is the behavior I would typically expect from Git's auto merge algorithm.

In the case where *both* branches changed the value of the variable, then there would be a merge conflict.  For example, if in commit `C3` the variable were changed to 5, then Git would not know whose version of the truth to default to, and it would therefore not auto merge, instead marking that line as a merge conflict.